# Firestore Failed to get document because the client is offline

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting an error while offline.

I already set the Persistence to `True` and getting some cached data while offline, but there is one function that gives me this offline error. The logcat point me on `task.getResult().exists()`.

I don't know what to do, can anyone help me?

> **ERROR:** com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Failed to get document because the client is offline.

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                    if(!task.getResult().exists()){ //I GET ERROR HERE

                        Map<String, Object> likesMap = new HashMap<>();
                        likesMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).set(likesMap);

                    } else {

                        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).delete();

                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: FYI any time you work with a Task, you should make sure to check to see if the task completed successfully, or there was an error.  Your code right now is blindly assuming that the task succeeded (which it did not).  If you're going to on onComplete, you should check the task for success or failure.  Or, you can split it up into an onSuccess and onFailure callbacks that get invoked depending on the status of the task.

Comment: But anyway, it sounds like the document you requested was not actually in your local cache.

Answer (score 1):

for me in flutter android app development process

- Open **android studio emulator** and choose **wipe data**
- and **run again**

**note:** I know only for android.